# How to update object with useState hook

Tags: react-native

I need to make state update and use it. I tried several ways, If I print `dropOffCoordinates` after I make the request and returned the response, even with `.then()` it doesn't update state. I tried having the `setDropOffCoordinates()` inside useEffect hook, it didn't work properly.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef } from "react";
const [dropOffCoordinates, setDropOffCoordinates] = useState({
   latitude: 0,
   longitude: 0
 });
const getCoordinatesofDropoffPlace = place_id => {
    getPlaceCoordinates(place_id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response drop off: ', response)
        setDropOffCoordinates( dropOffCoordinates => 
          ({
            ...dropOffCoordinates,
            latitude: response.lat,
            longitude: response.lng
          })
        );
        console.log("after: ", dropOffCoordinates)
      })
      .then( () => console.log('dropOffCoordinates', dropOffCoordinates) )
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
useEffect(
    () => {
      getCoordinatesofDropoffPlace
    }, [dropOffCoordinates]
   )
```

I call this function inside my component in a touchable opacity onPress function

```
onPress={ () => {
    getCoordinatesofDropoffPlace(place.place_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call setState. React will prepare to update application tree, but variable dropOffCoordinates still the same. I will try to:

1. create my position object and use it, and setState at the end of the process

```
getPlaceCoordinates(place_id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response drop off: ', response)
        console.log("component coordinates will be the same until reload", dropOffCoordinates)
        const coordinates = {
          latitude: response.lat,
          longitude: response.lng
        }

        // do your job with coordinates
        setDropOffCoordinates(coordinates)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

2. I will update and do an effect on change

```
const [dropOffCoordinates, setDropOffCoordinates] = React.useState({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0
  });
  const getCoordinatesofDropoffPlace = place_id => {
    getPlaceCoordinates(place_id)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response drop off: ", response);
        const newCoordinates = {
          latitude: response.lat,
          longitude: response.lng
        }
        // you can use newCorrdinates to do your job
        setDropOffCoordinates(newCoordinates);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // DO HERE YOUR JOB ON UPDATE
  }, [dropOffCoordinates]);
```